# Regex library for simple grep program in c

Tags: library, c, regex

I would like to try to write simple grep program in c.

I am aware of the [Ken Thompson version from 1968](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7%2Fusr%2Fsrc%2Fcmd%2Fgrep.c), where he himself implemented a regex compiler. However, I don't necessarily want to write my own regex library.

Which existing regex library on linux could I use, if I only need `egrep` functionality (not the extended Perl version: `grep -P`)

I know `libpcre` exists, but I assume that is for the `PCRE` version of `grep`

Comment: Edited the title to make it sound on topic.